# Unknown icon when using Subclipse 1.6.5

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

I use the SVN plugin, Subclipse, for the Eclipse IDE.  I recently noticed one of my directories get tagged with the icon seen below.  After reviewing the Subclipse label decorators, I didn't see this one.  Does anyone know what it represents?

[image: Mystery Subclipse icon]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It means you have a versioned SVN property modification.

Comment: Where did you find that answer?