# Java Class file showing question mark

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a java web project in which I created new class files. 
But there is a question mark (?) showing on the class file icon. 
Will this interfere with the execution of my project?
Why is the question mark showing?

---

**The icon in question:**

[image: The icon]

Comment: _It cause or stops the execution_. Why don't check this yourself.

Comment: It just means it was changed and *not* compiled since then.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Eclipse Java Package Explorer show question mark on some classes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4307086/why-does-eclipse-java-package-explorer-show-question-mark-on-some-classes)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It means that the file is new and is not present yet in the repository. You need to commit it.

Comment: Hey! thanx it worked. I committed and it helped to remove the question marks appearing in the java class file.