# Eclipse class have ? on the file. can someone please tell me what does that mean?

Tags: java, eclipse, class

[image]

The class files have question mark. If someone could please tell me what does it mean? and How do I correct it?

Comment: sometimes mean's a library is out of sync

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4307086/why-does-eclipse-java-package-explorer-show-question-mark-on-some-classes