# Red arrow icon in subclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive

My computer set-up:

-eclipse with aptana studio 3 plugin, plugin development tools and subclipse

and i have 2 projects under version control. i managed to copy the files from one project to the second since i don't know how to merge two projects yet. when i tried to copy the js folder from one project to the other, this happens:

[image]

notice the red arrow. now, i thought it was nothing. i committed the project and left for work. when i went to the office and updated my copy of the project, i found out that the js folder was not there. when i checked the repository, the js folder was not there at all. i was sure it was there when i left home.

found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917925/what-do-the-arrow-icons-in-subclipse-mean) which is a thread that gives an heads-up on subversion icons but this red outward pointing icon isnt there in the list.

what do they mean?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The arrow indicates switched 
http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/documentation/teamSupport/svn_label_decor.php

Comment: so how do i overcome this "switched" thing?

Comment: has the folder been switched in the local or in the svn itself. Check the svn mapping if out of sync with the parent folder mapping and if not intended and may be just revert the changes

Comment: what i did was copy (in eclipse) the js folder to the second project . when i looked into the actual files (windows explorer), the js folder is there in the second project's location. (sort of local, i suppose)

i have read somewhere else that copying folders under svn's control also copies the hidden .svn folder, which makes life difficult in copying files.

Comment: The copy has copied the .svn files as well. You can remove the .svn folders and this would change the icon to the one not checked in svn. You can then add it to your repository, if needed, or let it be just in local.

Comment: i knew it! i followed your advice and that did it! that .svn folder is a pain! there was no option to remove it from eclipse. Thanks!

Answer (score 34):

Using Eclipse Mars.1 Release (4.5.1) and SVN 1.8.10.  My icons reverted back to normal after running Team > Cleanup.

Comment: Solved my problem! This is what I would try first - before deleting the .svn folder or disconnecting and reconnectiong.

Answer (score 11):

I see there is already a solution in the comments above, just thought id share my **solution which seemed easier** , simply

1. Right click on project > Team > Disconnect (from repository)
2. Right click on project > Team > Re-connect (to repository)
3. Problem solved!

NOTE: After re-connecting had to commit all changes in project, seemed scary at first but simply updated version number. (I am always a little nervous when synchronizing with the repo)

NOTE: Using subversion SVN plugin in eclipse

Comment: Are you using the SVN plugin in eclipse?

Comment: I couldn't find "Re-connect", I used "Share project", it will do the same thing