# What does the blue arrow with red x icon in Subclipse mean?

Tags: java, eclipse, subclipse

There is a very good answer to a more general version of my question [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917925/what-do-the-arrow-icons-in-subclipse-mean) but I am seeing a blue arrow (file that has content changes committed to the repository that will be applied to the local copy.) with a RED X over it.  What does that mean?

Comment: It possibly means that the file is conflicted.

Comment: That would be a new module or directory that was attached to Subversion version control, then deleted before a commit.  Not a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The red X means the file is marked for delete. Note that the red x will sometimes appear (somewhat confusingly) on a file which has been simply renamed, or a file which was replaced. But typically the source control system (in my case perforce) handles it all correctly when you sync and submit.