# Android Eclipse red wildcard/star/*

Tags: java, android, eclipse, svn

I'm working on a radio app with the Android Java SDK and there's a strange symbol that's not in the eclipse database or documented anywhere that I've looked.

The error symbol appears like any other, in the place where a yellow "!" triangle or a red "x" box or circle would. This one is a red box with a white "*" (kinda looks like a snowflake).

[image: the symbol]

The folder it's on (and then bounced recursively up), is my res drawable-hdpi and drawable-mdpi, and the bin. Deleting them does nothing to the status of the res folder (except make the layouts bug out and toss an error). Another thing to note about the folders is that they gained a ">" before the title (so "> res" and ">drawable-hdpi"). The bin also only has res (no symbols or files) and the Android Manifest.

If anybody has dealt with this or has any ideas. They are highly welcomed.

Comment: I guess it has something to with version control. Do you use any plugin related to version control?

Comment: Thanks @AndrewT. I don't think that I did, but where would I go about looking to see if I did? Wouldn't that affect one of my source files as opposed to these folders (which contain pictures). Maybe something with the manifest.

Comment: Before that, could you capture the picture and post the link of it here? Without picture, it's a bit hard to conclude...

Comment: I figured as much, here we go: http://gyazo.com/f9fd22321254ce4c7790a65c08e1948c

Comment: I guess it's not red, but looks brown to me, so I was doubtful to elaborate more previously... and yes, apparently it has something to do with subversion. [This answer on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3920248/2821954) has information regarding the symbol :)

Comment: Thank you very much. And here I thought that color blindness wouldn't affect me in programming.