# What Eclipse/Subversive icon is this little diagonal arrow?

Tags: eclipse, adt, eclipse-juno, subversive

I have noticed this strange icon on my `AndroidManifest.xml` recently:

[image: File with strange icon]

It looks like either a diagonal arrow or a box "leaking" something at the bottom right.

I must have gone through

- [This](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-icons.htm) (Juno Icons)
- [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3920248/2135787) (List of Subclipse icons in SO answer)
- [and this](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/documentation/teamSupport/workspace_synch.php) (Subversive Documentation)

a hundred times but I am not able to find it anywhere.

As I am using `Subversive` for Subversion integration I suspect it has something to do with it. Other plugins I use are `m2e`, `FindBugs` and `EclipseMetrics`. The IDE is an Eclipse Juno ADT

Does anyone have an idea what this icon means? I'm really curious

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AndroidManifest.xml` is a linked file. These files/folder also called as Virtual files/folders. Right click on the linked/virtual resource(file/folder) and click on `Properties` to know more about it.

Refer [Eclipse News and Noteworthy](http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.6-201006080911/eclipse-news-part1.html) and [Link to Files and Folders in Eclipse](http://java.dzone.com/articles/link-files-and-folders-eclipse) for more details

Comment: This is great, absolutely correct, there must have been some hiccup in eclipse since the file linked to itself in the exact same path. Deleting and restoring fixed it and the arrow is now gone

Answer (score 1):

There are similar arrows in the [Web Tools Platform](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.wst.xsdeditor.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Frxsdicons.html), meaning *reference* (as in *group reference* or in *attribute reference*). So I suppose in your case it might be a *file reference* to an xml file.