# What is reason for yellow exclamation mark ("!") in eclipse java project(package and classes)?

Tags: java, eclipse, error-handling, project

Previously my project was in another machine. Then I added project into my new machine. After that I got error "error could not find or load main class". Then I remove JRE system library and again add. After that remove unused jar files and save the java build path. After that previous error removed and all code work finely. But every packages and classes from the beginning it shows yellow color exclamation mark. Doesn't give any error message. What is reason for that? How I remove it? Not red color. That's yellow color. (This happened to previously[image] exist classes and packages. Not for newly creates classes)

![enter image description here][2]

Comment: Please open Problems view and see what does it report. If something is unclear please post the screen capture or warning/error text.

Comment: Maybe the dependencies you use for a project is either moved or deleted i.e eclipse cannot find the file you referenced.

Comment: @AlexR previously my project work finely. This problem occurred when I'm changing the machine.

Comment: @DarshanLila How can I solve it?

Comment: Adding requires dependencies. If it's a problem.

Comment: The information you sent is not enough. Please consult problems view.

Comment: @AlexR That gives class dependency validator message. How can I solve it? My previous machine worked it. What does that mean? That shows class path entry messages.

Comment: OK, this is some information. What is the exact message?

Comment: @AlexR I added picture of some warning message. What that dependency mean? My previous machine not gave any message like that.

Comment: Check referenced libraries. Are they accessible?

Comment: @AlexR using my sql connector jar file I'm doing several things. Even yet not give an error message. I couldn't find way to solve this. If I work this way, is it possible to make problem in future code? Some one said to me "delete those references first and then add again". How can I do it?

Comment: @Maduri, please answer the questions you are asked. If I ask question I have a reason for this. I spend my time to help you. Generally your problem is either in the classpath itself or in project configuration. If I'd be in front of your monitor Id'd solve the problem within 45 seconds. So, if you really need help, please check again that paths to jars are really valid. You said that you moved to other machine. Is there a chance that jars do not exist there?

Comment: @AlexR Sorry dear. All jar files exist. I didn't remove anything. Only added some new few jar files.

Comment: Try to redefine dependencies of the project again. (Right click on project, select properties, go to classpath...) See that eclipse does not complain on any dependency.

Comment: @AlexR Thanx lot for wasting your time. Solved it. That was dependency problem. I had added two places. Thanx lot. Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 7):

These exclamation marks are denoting warnings. This sign will appear on the packages which contains classes with warnings (like unused imports, unused variables, using raw types, etc.). You can reach the class containing warnings and have a look what's causing these warnings. Once found, depending on the warning, you can take necessary actions.

Comment: This problem occurred when I'm changing the project one machine to another and added new jar files and classes of another machine. My previous machine not shown anything.

Answer (score 4):

In Eclipse, these are often caused by Java compiler warnings, and can also be caused by various validation warnings (for XML files, JSP files, etc.)

To see the warning messages, go to Window => Show View => Problems.

This is a fairly comprehensive list from the Eclipse documentation.  If anyone knows of another list — maybe with more details, or just the most common icons — feel free to add it.

Juno: [JDT Icons](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-icons.htm)

Indigo: [JDT Icons](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-icons.htm)

There are also some CDT icons at the bottom of this [help page][1].

If you're a Subversion user, the icons you're looking for may actually belong to Subclipse; see [this excellent answer]:[What do the arrow icons in Subclipse mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917925/what-do-the-arrow-icons-in-subclipse-mean/3920248#3920248) for more on those.

http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/reference/cdt_u_cproj_view.htm

Comment: I went through problem section. That gives class dependency validator message. How I solve it?

Comment: Remove it here: Preferences -> Validation -> Classpath Dependency Validator

Also check if your specific project has its own validation settings overwritting the global ones. Project -> Properties -> Validation

Comment: remove mean tick off the class path dependency row (manual and build) ? Is that my project problem or is it ok to remove tick off? In that validation dialog box tick is there on the "Allow projects to override these preferences setting".

Comment: tick off the class path dependency row

Comment: Ok. So I figured it out. . . in order to get it to work right, I have to "drop and drag" the files that I want in my classpath/dependencies into my WEB-INF/lib file. It works this way. For some reason when I try to do it the right way build path --> configure build path --> external jars it just doesnt take.

Comment: I also thought good and correct way to fist add to web-inf/lib file and then add to class path. Thanx dear.

Answer (score 0):

Goto windows>showview>and select problems

[image]

This will show the details:

[image]