# Eclipse SVN Team View "Add to Version Control" is grayed out - why?

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

I'm working on a project in Eclipse, and our version control is in Subversion. My exact Eclipse info is Eclipse CDT Mars, 4.5.1, with Subclipse 1.10.9 .

So, I created this extran file, and I want to add it to version control, but - for some reason that's grayed out on the team menu, along with some other items:

[image]

Why is that? Or rather, what could be the reasons for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Add to Version Control option only shows up when the selected item has a Subversion status of "unversioned".  I would guess that your file is already considered versioned or scheduled add by Subversion or maybe it is ignored.

Comment: Hmm. It was probably scheduled for addition, since when I `svn commit`ed on the command line, they did go in. I wish this was clearer in the UI.

Comment: Items that are scheduled Add have a + decorator on them.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917925/what-do-the-arrow-icons-in-subclipse-mean/3920248#3920248