# SVN checked out file icon in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

My workspace is in Sync with the SVN Repository but one of the files' icon does not reflect that. The first icon is proper but I am unable to find the meaning of the second icon. Team Sync says there is neither any outgoing changes nor any incoming changes.

[image]

I have gone through this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917925/what-do-the-arrow-icons-in-subclipse-mean/3920248#3920248), but it does not have explanation for the second icon.

Comment: I cannot really tell what that icon is from the screenshot.  It does not look like anything Subclipse provides or uses.

Comment: It maybe looks like the conflict icon exists underneath another icon?  And the one on top maybe looks like the tree conflict icon?  If you have SVN command line available run svn status from the root of the working copy.

Comment: There is no confusion with the first icon, it shows that the file is in sync with SVN. My query was for the second icon. The _svn stat_ command did not list that file for which the second icon is shown.

Comment: I assumed it was obvious we are only talking about the second icon.  Subclipse info comes from svn status so if it does not show anything then that further reinforces the notion that the icon does not come from Subclipse.

Comment: Thank you @MarkPhippard for the clarification. I will keep a watch in my workspace if this icon appears again and will run _svn stat_ instantly.