# SVN: file that doesn't even exist need to commit

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

I have a folder contains three files:

```
--mapper
 |--a.xml
 |--b.xml
```

Someday, a new file `c.xml` is added in the repo. I updated project in Eclipse with the Subclipse plugin, then `c.xml` showed in the folder, but marked with a red cross icon which means something wrong I suppose. So I went to the synchronize perspective, choose the `mapper` folder, then overwrite this folder in local, then c.xml is deleted, why it is deleted? Overwrite means replace my local file with the files exactly in the repo, right?

Another weird thing is that in the sync perspective, there is a `x.java` file with modifications needs to be committed, it is not in the local folder either. I don't even write Java, even I had made a modification by mistake I am not aware of, it should not be in the `mapper` folder.

I have been working on this problem since last Friday, the last couple of times when I met this I just move the project to other place and checkout a new one, but this time I did not want to choose the stupid way.

Comment: Which [icon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3920248/6505250) do you mean exactly? The _History_ and the _SVN Repositories_ view show what happens on the server and if it is a conceptual SVN problem. If not, you can try a different SVN client (e. g. Eclipse Subversive). The `x.java` file might be generated by a project builder that generates code (this does not sound like an SVN or an SVN client problem). Instead of checkout the whole project you can also delete the parent folder where the problem occurs and then replace it with the latest from the SVN repository.

Comment: What does svn status say?

Comment: @Yeti svn: E200009: Wrong number of targets has been specified (0), at least 1 is required