# Eclipse warning like icon on every file inspite of no actual warning

Tags: eclipse

I have a project opened on eclipse and i have no warning or errors but i get this icon appearing on my files. I have magnified it since it was hard to make out what it actually was

[image]

The actual icon is best seen when you open the image in a new tab.

What is that icon and how can i make it go away?.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this answer: [What do the arrow icons in Subclipse mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917925/what-do-the-arrow-icons-in-subclipse-mean/3920248#3920248)

It looks like the svn source control status icon for unmodified files.

Comment: I have right clicked on the project and disconnected team  since i am tracking with git already. Thanks @StephaneM